# Recommended CORS Allow and Expose Headers

Tags: nginx, http-headers, cors

[enable-cors.org nginx config](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html) suggests using the below values for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`.  But there isn't much explanation of **why** these are recommended except `Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't`.  I'd rather not inflate the payload for every API request if some of these are not needed for my application.

I know I could remove them and wait for something to break but I'm hoping for some background on why/how they were selected so I can make a more educated decision on whether they are necessary for my application. i.e. were they recommended to support a browser that my application doesn't need to support?

**Access-Control-Allow-Headers**: `DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range`

**Access-Control-Expose-Headers**: `DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range`

For the `Allow-Headers`, I can understand for most of them why a client would want to send them.  `X-CustomHeader` stands out as an oddball though.  Also, I tested on Chrome that even if `User-Agent` isn't explicitly allowed, chrome still sends it.  This implies that these options were added for browser compatibility that my app might not need.

For the `Expose-Headers`, it seems like it would be very application specific on which headers a client needs to read.  Why would a client need to *read* `User-Agent`, `DNT`, or `X-Requested-With`?  They contain info meant for the server to consume, not the client.  Additionally, `Cache-Control` and `Content-Range` are already [enabled by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) so they seem redundant here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up going through each header and determining if it was necessary.  I compiled a list of changes:

- Changes for both `Allow` and `Expose`

  - Removed from both since they are non-standard headers

    - `X-CustomHeader`
  - Removed from both since they are non-standard and semi-deprecated

    - [Keep-Alive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive)
- Changes for `Allow`:

  - Removed since they are *response*-specific headers (used only for
    servers to inform client)

    - `Content-Range`
  - Kept even though they are enabled by default but only for certain
    types of requests ([as per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)):

    - `Content-Type`
- Changes for `Expose`:

  - Removed since they are already enabled by default ([as per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers))

    - `Cache-Control`
    - `Content-Type`
  - Removed since they are *request*-specific headers (used only for
    clients to inform server)

    - `DNT`
    - `User-Agent`
    - `X-Requested-With`
    - `If-Modified-Since`
    - `Range`
  - Added since they seem useful

    - `Content-Length`

This leaves me with the following:

**Access-Control-Allow-Headers**: `DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range`

**Access-Control-Expose-Headers**: `Content-Length,Content-Range`

Any comments or corrections would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/monsur/enable-cors.org/issues/133) and [PR](https://github.com/monsur/enable-cors.org/issues/134) on enable-cors.org for these changes.

Comment: Note that the PR was accepted which means enable-cors.org now officially suggests these changes.  See [enable-cors.org nginx config](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html) for their latest config.